# I am getting the error: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, graph, array-broadcasting

I want to plot a bar graph for **labels in y axis and on x axis the number of datapoints** each label has. But I am getting the following error, can anyone please help me with the correct code?
I am writing this code to visualize the number of datapoints divided among labels (0,1,2,3,4...9).

```
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

     pip install watermark
     %load_ext watermark
     %watermark -u -v -d -p matplotlib,numpy
     %matplotlib inline
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input data
mean_values = [0, 1500, 0,   0,   6000, 1000, 1500, 2000, 1200] #y labels
bar_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8','9'] #x_labels

# plot bars
x_pos = list(range(len(bar_labels)))
rects = plt.bar(x_pos, mean_values, align='center', alpha=0.5)

# label bars
def autolabel(rects):
    for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.02*height, '%s'% (mean_values[ii]),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects)
    


# set height of the y-axis
max_y = max(zip(mean_values, variance)) # returns a tuple, here: (3, 5)
plt.ylim([0, (max_y[0] + max_y[1]) * 1.1])

# set axes labels and title
plt.ylabel('variable y')
plt.xticks(x_pos, bar_labels)
plt.title('Bar plot with labels')

plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-25c2776ed492> in <module>
      7 # plot bars
      8 x_pos = list(range(len(bar_labels)))
----> 9 rects = plt.bar(x_pos, mean_values, align='center', alpha=0.5)
     10 
     11 # label bars

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2407     return gca().bar(
   2408         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
-> 2409         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2410 
   2411 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2340         x, height, width, y, linewidth = np.broadcast_arrays(
   2341             # Make args iterable too.
-> 2342             np.atleast_1d(x), height, width, y, linewidth)
   2343 
   2344         # Now that units have been converted, set the tick locations.

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in broadcast_arrays(subok, *args)
    536     args = [np.array(_m, copy=False, subok=subok) for _m in args]
    537 
--> 538     shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
    539 
    540     if all(array.shape == shape for array in args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    418     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    419     # consistently
--> 420     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    421     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    422     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: the error message doesn't fit to the code you posted. please fix that.

Comment: It's telling you that there's a mismatch between the 2 plot arguments.  One has 9 values, and the other 10!   `broadcasting` is a  general tool in numpy for mixing and matching multidimensional arrays.  Some mixes work, orthers, such as this, don't.

Comment: @Rabinzel just fixed it, thank you ! Can you please check it once